Moving grid with different objects in geo nodes
I want to know how to achieve this effect with geo nodes, I want to move each row and column individually

We need to know your setup. The answer depends on how you are creating this grid of objects.

I am using a grid and instance on points

To move each row individually, for each element calculate which row it is on, and based on that number, move. That is, if you move randomly, you will want to use the row number as the "ID" of the "Random Value" node. If it's not random, but e.g. moving rows in alternate directions, then you will use a switch checking if the row number is even (modulo 2).
How do you obtain row number? Many options:

Instance rows on a column of points. Now if the column of points has indices in order (If you're not using mesh line, you could still sort them using "Sort" node with "Position" passed to "Separate XYZ" and using one of the components of the position as weight), then you can capture instance indices or directly indices mod 2, to then use that after realizing those instances.

"Grid" node, which produces stable indices (see: geometry-randomization) + simple index logic using divmod (How to get row and column from index?)

You could pass "Position" → "Separate XYZ", and pass one of the components through "Math: Wrap", and if you align it with the topology (double the row height) you can then compare the number with a value that should be only on one row...



Thank you! How can I find modulo 2?

@TiagoMartinez Math node
